# Embedded MP3 Player on Web Page

Tags: c#, html, .net, media-player, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to embed an mp3 album on a web page and wanted to know if there are any good solutions out there for this that other people have used and would recommend.  I'm looking for something that doesn't cost anything and allows users to play the entire album, selected songs and also ideally download the MP3s as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the video tag to act as a music player:

```
<video controls><source src="AUDIO FILE" type="audio/mp3">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
```

example:

```
<video controls><source src="http://mcrocks999.netai.net/m/%5bElectro%5d%20-%20Insan3Like3%20-%20Bad%20Pitched%20(Original%20Mix)%20%5bMonstercat%20VIP%20Release%5d.mp3" type="audio/mp3">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
```

EDIT: I just found this: http://musicplayer.sourceforge.net/ might be helpful.